# Invocation Error in Xaml Page in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's my question in xamarin forums but until now, I got no answer yet

```
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/71026/xaml-page-error-when-binding-date-from-viewmodel-class#latest
```

Comment: I think you'll have better results if you ask the question here, and not just link to your question somewhere else. StackOverflow tends to dislike questions/answers that are purely links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the answer. Please see the link and I put the answer there.